# How to assign a set of Azure Web Sites to a specific set of instances?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

For the same reasons the "Standard" mode isolates Azure Web Sites from specific subscriptions from each other, a single account holder (company) might want to isolate Azure Web Sites within a single subscription from each other. Is it possible?

Note: We only have a single subscription to test things out, so we *assume* that web sites from different subscriptions are isolated, but it might be a bad assumption.

Comment: Windows Azure Web Sites is a multi-tenant model. As such, what exactly are you trying "isolate". If this purely from a management standpoint? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @BrentDaCodeMonkey: From what I understand, the whole point of "Standard mode" over "Shared/Free modes" is that all sites under a subscription share an instance *dedicated* to that subscription.  I also get that these instances themselves share hardware with other instances, but AFAICT their performance is way more predictable compared to that of a site that shares an instance with other sites.  Is that not correct?  If it is, the question is about having the flexibility to organize sites into groups to make sure one doesn't impact the performance of another, even within a single subscription.

Comment: My bad, I was still stuck back in the "reserved" days. :) To my knowledge, you can't currently select which sites get placed into the dedicated guest VM. When you promote to standard (aka reserved), it will pull in all the sites on that subscription that are in the same region (aka datacenter) up to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Hosting Plans feature in Azure Web Site can help with isolating sites in "Standard" mode between each other. For example you can create two (or more) web hosting plans, put different sites in them and then scale those web hosting plans to "Standard". Azure will allocate different sets of VM's to each Web Hosting Plan and sites will be isolated from each other.

More information here:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the suggestion *"[it should be possible to scale websites individually, even when they are in same region](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-sites/suggestions/5103344-it-should-be-possible-to-scale-websites-individual)"* is spot on regarding this issue.  The idea is "under review" as of Dec 23, 2013, so the current answer is that **no, it isn't possible yet**.

---

**Update:** Closed (WONTFIX) as of March 20, 2014, though apparently based on a misunderstanding or simply incorrect information (see comment on the suggestion thread). There's still a chance they might reopen when they realize this (or when the issue pops up again in the future), though I wouldn't rely on this assumption.

---

Thanks [BrentDaCodeMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512346/brentdacodemonkey) for clarifying that sites are grouped to run on sets of instances within regions / data centers as opposed to just by subscription.  I guess a "work-around" would be to isolate sites in different data centers, though it's likely that it may be more cumbersome than anything in many cases.

---

**Update:** [Feature announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/04/introducing-web-hosting-plans-for-azure-web-sites.aspx) on April 4, 2014.